# TLS handshake timeout when load testing using Gatling

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, kubernetes, gatling

I currently load testing my service using Gatling in AWS. I did several load tests using HTTP and my service works perfectly. No TLS handshake errors. When we moved to the HTTPS, the load test result showed **TLS handshake timeout** exception all over the place and finally thrown OOM because unprocessed request getting queued.

Additional information:

- The Gatling scenario will be like this:
  Sends three requests and send one request with the `connection: close` header. I wanted to simulate sending three requests that is kept alive and close it at the end.
- My service is managed by Kubernetes.

What I have done:

- I ran the load test on other Gatling instance, but the error still persists
- Restarted the AWS load balancer. Additional notes: There are no 4xx and 5xx errors, but we have client TLS negotiation errors.

My questions:

1. Is the error occurred because of the initial handshake required for the HTTPS?
2. Is the error occurred because of the AWS load balancer?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems the problem was because the time it took for Gatling to handshake longer than the creation users per second. By decreasing the number of users created and increasing the number RPS solved that.

Comment: Hi Vincent, can you add some description around the solution. If possible add a code snippet of the gatling injection script/query?

Comment: How to increase number of rps?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a SSL debug flag to the client - it will show the nature of the error. A TLS handshake timeout is usually due to cipher/protocol mismatch.

Find out the specific TLS protocol and set of ciphers that the Gatling server is using and make sure your ELB HTTPS listener is using the correct cipher and protocol

From [SSL Negotiation Configurations for Classic Load Balancers](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-ssl-security-policy.html)

> Elastic Load Balancing uses a Secure Socket Layer (SSL) negotiation
>   configuration, known as a security policy, to negotiate SSL
>   connections between a client and the load balancer. A security policy
>   is a combination of SSL protocols, SSL ciphers, and the Server Order
>   Preference option. For more information about configuring an SSL
>   connection for your load balancer, see Listeners for Your Classic Load
>   Balancer.

Try to allow all ciphers/protocols there.